# JS toggle buttons not operating

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am relatively new to using Javascirpt and attempting to build a web map. I'm not able to toggle different attributes in my web map due to issues in the javascript file, which is my main issue after changing parameters many times.

Here's the code below;

HTML:

```
<div class="map-overlay" id="togglebox"> 
    <div class="type" id="filter"> 
        <div>
            <input id='all' type='radio' name='toggle' value='all' checked='checked'>
            <label for='all'>Display All</label>
            <input id='Open' type='radio' name='toggle' value='Open'>
            <label for='Open'>Open</label>
            <input id='Closed' type='radio' name='toggle' value="Closed">
            <label for='Closed'>Closed</label>
            <input id='Malt' type='radio' name='toggle' value='Malt'>
            <label for='Malt'>Malt</label>
            <input id='Grain' type='radio' name='toggle' value='Grain'>
            <label for='Grain'>Grain</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
    filterAccess = ['!=', ['get', 'type'], 'placeholder'];

    document.getElementById('filter').addEventListener('change', (event) => {
        const type = event.target.value;
        console.log(type);
        if (type == "all") {
            filterAccess = ['!=', ['get', 'type'], 'placeholder'];
        } else if (type == "Open") { 
            filterAccess = ['==', ['get', 'type'], 'Open'];
        } else if (type == 'Closed') {
            filterAccess = ['==', ['get', 'type'], 'Closed'];
        } else if (type == 'Malt') {
            filterAccess = ['==', ['get', 'type'], 'Malt'];
        } else if (type == "Grain") { 
            filterAccess = ['==', ['get', 'type'], 'Grain'];
        } else {
            console.log("error");
        }
        map.setFilter("Whisky", ["all", filterAccess]);
    });
```

I've tried going through mapbox help guides and tutorials but to no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// Set the initial filter to display all features
let filterAccess = ['!=', ['get', 'type'], 'placeholder'];

// Listen for changes to the radio buttons
document.getElementById('filter').addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    const type = event.target.value;  // Get the value of the selected radio button
    console.log(type);
    if (type == "all") {  // If "Display All" is selected
        filterAccess = ['!=', ['get', 'type'], 'placeholder'];  // Show all features
    } else if (type == "Open") {  // If "Open" is selected
        filterAccess = ['==', ['get', 'type'], 'Open'];  // Only show features with type "Open"
    } else if (type == 'Closed') {  // If "Closed" is selected
        filterAccess = ['==', ['get', 'type'], 'Closed'];  // Only show features with type "Closed"
    } else if (type == 'Malt') {  // If "Malt" is selected
        filterAccess = ['==', ['get', 'type'], 'Malt'];  // Only show features with type "Malt"
    } else if (type == "Grain") {  // If "Grain" is selected
        filterAccess = ['==', ['get', 'type'], 'Grain'];  // Only show features with type "Grain"
    } else {  // If an invalid value is selected
        console.log("error");  // Log an error message
    }
    map.setFilter("Whisky", ["all", filterAccess]);  // Update the filter for the "Whisky" layer
});
```